# Image background subtraction using parallel computing

Tags: programming, image-processing, parallelization

I am developing a program for pattern recognition. I want to use the parallel computing to get a real time application.

I have two cameras where each one gives n frames/second. I need to process the data given by both cameras (i.e background subtraction) in the same time using the parallel computing as shown in the image:

I can use `ImageSubtract[]` or `ImageDifference[]` for background subtraction. So the question is how I can Evaluate two functions (i.e `ImageSubtract` with different inputs) in the same time?

Which package is used on *Mathematica* for parallel computing? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Please do not put keywords or technical phrases in `code` tags.  Use **bold** or *italics* for emphasis.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,sorry!. I will edit my question!

Comment: No need, I just did.

Comment: By the way I think I (re?)created the "threading" tag today and now I see why it probably didn't exist: confusion between the meaning I intended i.e. `Thread` and evaluation threads.  I have removed it from this question as I think `parallel` is sufficient and less ambiguious.  I should probably think of a different tag for `Thread`-like behavior.

Answer (score 2):

We can try like this:

```
Parallelize[MapThread[ImageSubtract, {{image1,image2}, {fond1,fond2}}]]
```

or

```
ParallelTry[imageSubtract, {{imag1, fond1}, {imag2, fond2}}, 2]
```

While

```
imageSubtract[{image_,fond_}]:=Module[{},(

Image[(ImageData[image1]-ImageData[fond1]+1)/2]
)]
```

We can use also `ParallelMap[]`

```
ParallelMap[imageSubtract, {{imag1, fond1}, {imag2, fond2}}, 2]
```

I remark that `Parallelize` is faster than `ParallelTry[]` and the `ParallelTry[]` is faster than `ParallelMap[]`
Any deep explanation about this? And it is possible to define `imageSubtract[image1,fond1]` and used it with ParallelTry[] and ParallelMap[] or I must to define it with one argument?

Comment: any explanation please?